# Is it possible to implement a ssl cert (HTTPS) on a website that has a different host and domain?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, host

There is a website that my team are working on to install SSL on it to secure the transactions on the website.

we are tasked to working on it to turn it to https but we found the site hosted by Exa Bytes Network Sdn.Bhd but the domain resides with Godaddy.

We heard that ssl is registered on the hosting site, but does it covers the domain part?

Is it possible ot install the ssl on the domain alone?

Comment: The hosting company is irrelevant, the domain registrar is irrelevant. You need an SSL certificate with the website address (`www.example.com`) in the Subject Name field, or in the Subject Alternative Name field, or a wildcard entry which covers the website address (e.g. `*.example.com`). And you need the private key for the certificate (i.e. you generated the CSR yourself). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

No, a certificate encrypts traffic all the way to the endpoint itself so it would need to be installed on the server. The setup you describe is very similar to many medium & large scale shops (domain is registered with one vendor but the site is hosted in house or within a professional cloud).

I think the problem you might be describing has to do with shared, hosted environments. Is this a shared hosting setup? The shared environments I've worked with made it difficult to use an external cert on their site. It is possible, technically speaking, though you are talking about providing the hosting provider with the private key to the cert (not something you'd email to them).